# Is there a CLR data type to Sql data type translation method?

Tags: clr, sqldatatypes

I was going through the MVC material over at asp.net, and came across the 5 minute introduction video:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/5-minute-introduction-to-aspnet-mvc

In this video, there was demonstration of creating a model, then having MVC generate a Sql table based on the object/model automatically.

My question is, what mechinism is used to translate the object's CLR datatypes to Sql Server datatypes?

I'd like to create a quick and dirty method to have similar functionality outside of MVC... something as simple as a method returning a Create Table string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe?

[MSDN - Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)

Or this?

[MSDN - SQL-CLR Type Mapping (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx)

Comment: Sort of what I'm looking for, but I do not want to (or have the ability to) modify the existing object.  Might have to just hard code a translation tool.